# Как не кэшировать динамические маршруты в Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, кэширование

Я пытаюсь добавить свой динамический маршрут как сервис

routes.yml:

```
 static_pages:
 resource: 'pages.dynamic_routing_provider:getRoutes'
 type: service
```

Service.php

```
class DynamicRoutingProvider {
public function getRoutes(): RouteCollection
{
$builder = new RouteCollectionBuilder();

 $options = [
 'cache_dir' => null,
 'generator_cache_class' => null
 ];

 $route = new Route('dynamic-pages', ['_controller' => 'PagesBundle:pages:preview'], [], $options);
 $builder->addRoute($route);

 return $builder->build();
 }
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы мой динамический маршрут не попадал в этот файл:

> /cache/appProductionDebugSilexProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php
>   /cache/appProductionDebugSilexProjectContainerUrlGenerator.php

Пример:

1) у меня есть маршрут localhost / dynamic-pages / page1
Затем в админ-панели я переименую свой маршрут для page2

2) у меня есть маршрут localhost / dynamic-pages / page1
Затем в админ-панели я удаляю этот маршрут.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719292/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-requirements-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-route-%D0%B0-symfony-3-3/773086#773086